# Firebase Analytics -> BigQuery how to query user_dim.user_properties within C#

Tags: c#, mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query my tables that were exported from firebase but am having issues accessing the values from within C#. I'm able to query anything with the prefix `user_dim` by just doing `SELECT user_dim.*` from the table but if I want to access `user_dim.user_properties.value` for example, I'm unable to and get `No such field: 'user_properties.value'`. The code below is working to query the table, it just doesn't grab all rows that I want.

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2;

namespace BigQueryExample
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
            string projectId = "hidden";

            // Instantiates a client
            BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);

            var table = client.GetTable("hidden", "hidden", "hidden");

            try
            {
                string query = $@"SELECT user_dim.* FROM `{table.FullyQualifiedId}` LIMIT 100";
                var result = client.ExecuteQuery(query);
                Console.Write("\nQuery Results:\n------------\n");
                foreach (var row in result.GetRows())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row["user_properties.value"]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }



            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great as to how I can get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply ran my query as:

```
SELECT user_dim.* FROM `table`
```

This grabs all columns under `user_dim`